# How to clear the text present in the EL ,jstl tag on refresh

Tags: java, spring, jstl, el

```
<c:if test="${hasSuccessMsg}">
        <div id="reportSuccessMsg" class="successMsg" align="center"> <img src="<c:url value="/images/ico_success.png"/>" class="vMiddle padRight10"> 
            ${reportSuccessMsg}
        </div>
    </c:if>
```

when i come to this page, i get my success message as i want, like 
    cutomer123-product123 added successfully ,
but when i reload i get null-null addedsuccess fully.

I want to clear the entire content on refresh. 
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

from on your el snippet, you just need to reset `hasSuccessMsg` flag

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate the requests whether this is a refresh or a form submit. This can be identified by having a hidden field in the form and check the value of the hidden field in the server side. After identifying the refresh request, you can make the value of 
`hasSuccessMsg` as false. Thus, the execution will not happen and `null` values will not be shown.

Note : You have to set the hidden field value during `submit` button `onclick` to differentiate the request type